# Double Function in C++

Tags: c++

I was stuck in the Chapter 3.3 Principles and Practice using C++:

He mentioned:-
Get the “name and age” example to run. Then, modify it to write out the age in months:
read the input in years and multiply (using the * operator) by 12. Read the age into a
double to allow for children who can be very proud of being five and a half years old
rather than just five.

Here is the name and age example that I ran with no problems:

```
    #include "std_lib_facilities.h"

    int main()

    {
    cout << "Please enter your name and age.\n";
    string name;            //string variable
    int age;                //integer variable
    cin >> name >> age;     //reads string and integer
    cout << "Hello, " << name << " (Age: " << age << ")\n";
    }
```

Afterwhich, I tried to change the age into months instead which I am able to achieve by using this:

```
    #include "std_lib_facilities.h"

    int main()
    {
    cout << "Please enter your name and age\n";
    string name;
    int age;
    cin >> name >> age;
    cout << "Hello, " << name << " (Age: " << age * 12 << " Months Old)\n";
    }
```

So the question remains is, how do I 'read the age into a double'? Even though I managed to get my output to show the age in months, I believe I've not clearly understand the way to tackle this question.

Comment: `int age;` -> `double age;`

Comment: Comments like `// string variable` are not that useful - self evident from the code

Comment: Simply define `age` as a `double`.

Comment: .. Also a good idea to check if the read from `stdin` was successful.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `double` as the type of the variable to read the data in.

```
// What is this?    
//#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your name and age\n";
    string name;
    double age;
    cin >> name >> age;
    cout << "Hello, " << name << " (Age: " << age * 12 << " Months Old)\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He is using the precompiled header "std_lib_facilities.h" which is created by Bjarne Stroustrup for new programmers.

Comment: This header enables new programmers to use common libraries without including them manually. It also lets the student to use library functions without std qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare age as double. Your problem should be solved.

**Sample code**

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
cout << "Please enter your name and age\n";
string name;
double age;
cin >> name >> age;
cout << "Hello, " << name << " (Age: " << age * 12 << " Months Old)\n";
}
```

Now the program should run without any problem.